# Cannot add servlet to Tomcat web.xml

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I've created a simple servlet web app in Eclipse (Java EE of course).
It runs on the Tomcat server I've configured locally in Eclipse.

I would like to run it on a Tomcat server using XAMPP, while leaving the app in Eclipse (not exporting JARs).
I've tried editing the web.xml but it did not work.

The URL for the home page is:
    localhost:8080/webstore/controller/index

Should I just copy the war file to webapps?

I quite new to this, please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't add web.xml to your Tomcat. You deploy (place) the whole war which includes web.xml under WEB-INF inside your jar. You either place to war file in the Tomcat webapps folder (typically) or you are using its manager under your.tomcat.address/manager

Comment: While it is less common, note that it IS possible to modify the conf/web.xml file that comes supplied with Tomcat.

Comment: Okay, its a bit more clear now and I've edited my question accordingly.

But at the moment I would like to leave my app in Eclipse and use an external Tomcat. This means that I need to copy the entire 'web content' folder to Tomcat webapps? or just place the war under a new folder in webapps?

Comment: Of course @KodeCharlie you are absolutelly right. But I assumed the use-case is not so advanced (the other approach is used mainly due to security constraints).

Comment: David what do you mean you want to leave your app in Eclipse. What are you trying to achieve. If your tomcat is not local than of course it cannot access the files under your eclipse project. If it is on the same machine, than you probably already configured Eclipse to use it cause as far as I know eclipse does not ship with its own tomcat (unlike Netbeans).

Comment: @Zielu, sorry I was indeed a bit unclear.
I working just on one machine. Eclipse has an option to download Tomcat and configure it automatically which I've done.

But now I would like to run the application with Tomcat server configured in XAMPP - which I've referred to "external".

So the "external" has access to the file system as its the same machine.